Альтернатива The Web Application Hacker's Handbook
Ищу книги по пентесту с упором на веб. Ищу что-то на подобие "The Web Application Hacker's Handbook: Finding and Exploiting Security Flaws" by Dafydd Stuttard and Marcus Pinto. Но там не работают ссылки с практическими заданиями. В общем ищу что-то похожие(чтение на английском не проблема). Может есть какие-то варианты?
